# Why is my JavaScript code ruining my styling?

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a login modal and want the content to be centered horizontally and vertically. My CSS has it centered how I want it, but when I added the JavaScript, it is only centered horizontally. What's wrong with my code? thanks!

I tried flexbox and every other centering method I know. It just doesnt make sense because if I comment out the JavaScript, the modal content is where I want it to be!

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('login-modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("login");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
  modal.style.display = "none";}
}



#login-modal{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align:center;
}

.login-content{
border: 10 px solid black;
height:12%;
width:20%;
background-color:white;
display:block;
text-align:center;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password]{
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You are setting `display = "block"`, you should set it to `flex` like the CSS original value.

Comment: .login-content{
border: 10 px solid black;
height:12%;
width:20%;
background-color:white;
display:block;
text-align:center;
flex-direction: column     <-----
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to initially hide something without regard to its display type in CSS, you can create the element with an inline display attribute of `style="display: none;"` in its HTML tag or, if creating the element in JavaScript, with `element.style.display="none"`.

After that, you can display an element by deleting its `element.style.display` property. The element reverts to whatever display type was given to it in CSS.

To hide it, add back `element.style.display="none";`

Using this approach, the modal should always appear as styled in CSS. However, don't try to change its display type to anything except `none` anywhere else in JavaSript!

To specifically answer the question, inline `style` attribute values have absolute priority over rules provided in CSS.